# React - update one item element in a list by "fetch"

Tags: reactjs, database, fetch

I'm learning React and I'm completely stuck with no idea about this issue.

I have a database with three columns:

- Id - string,
- Item - string,
- Packed - boolean.

Everything (adding, deleting, showing list) works but not this one: update item. I want to update only "packed" to "true" or "false" value. I want to click a button "Update Item" to updating state in a column "Packed" for "Yes" or "null" (for one element). Everything I tried had "400 (Bad Request)" (ID is read correctly). It works correctly in Swagger with REST API. For now, I want to try clear React. This is my code:

```
    import React from 'react';

    class ClothesList extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                id: '',
                item: '',
                packed: false,
                clothes: [],
                error: null
            };
            this.deleteClothes = this.deleteClothes.bind(this);
            this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            fetch('/api/v1/clothes')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(
                    data => {
                        this.setState({
                            clothes: data
                        });
                    },
                    error => {
                        this.setState({
                            error
                        });
                    }
                )
        }

        deleteClothes(id) {
            fetch(`/api/v1/clothes/${id}`, {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }).then(() => {
                let updatedClothes = [...this.state.clothes].filter(i => i.id !== id);
                this.setState({
                    clothes: updatedClothes,
                });
            });
        }

        updateItem(id) {

            const { item, packed } = this.state;

            fetch(`/api/v1/clothes/${id}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ item, packed })
            });
        }

        render() {
            const { clothes, error } = this.state;

            if (error) {
                return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
            }

            const clothesList = clothes.map(c => {
                return <tr key={c.id}>
                    <td>{c.id}</td>
                    <td>{c.item}</td>
                    <td>{c.packed === true ? <span>Yes</span> : null}</td>
                    <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => this.deleteClothes(c.id)}>Delete</button>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.updateItem(c.id)}>Update Item</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            });

            return (
                <div>
                    <h3>Clothes</h3>
                    <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Item</th>
                                <th>Packed</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {clothesList}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default ClothesList;
```

```
Swagger request - it works. There is an object in a body:

[![Swagger request][1]][1]

And this is the update method in ClothesService (Java Spring):
```

```
     @Transactional
        public ClothesDTO updateClothes(String id, ClothesDTO newClothesData) throws DataInvalid, NotFound {
            validateClothesDTO(newClothesData);

            Clothes clothes = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFound());
            clothes.setItem(newClothesData.getItem());
            clothes.setPacked(newClothesData.isPacked());

            Clothes savedClothes = repository.save(clothes);

            return mapper.mapToClothesDTO(savedClothes);
        }
```

Comment: Please explain this a little more: "Everything works but one: update item"

Comment: what problem do you get

Comment: Adding, deleting, showing list - these things work.
I want to click a button "Update Item" to updating state in a column "Packed" for "Yes" or "null" (for one element).

Comment: a status 400 means that it was a bad request -
can you please include what the endpoint is supposed to accept (e.g. swagger file for the clothes resource)

Comment: I have included "Swagger Request" to the main question.

Comment: what does newClothesData object shape require - (please give an example)

Comment: perhaps we need to include id within the body of `newClothesData?`

Comment: OK. I think I know what's probably the point. "c.packed" from "clothesList" in the "table" returns "Yes" or "null", but in this case boolean is required (true or false). So, how to change the value of "c.packed" to boolean for "updateItem"? And how to pass it to this method? Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I got it! It works:

```
import React from 'react';

class ClothesList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clothes: [],
            error: null
        };
        this.deleteClothes = this.deleteClothes.bind(this);
        this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this);
        this.isPacked = this.isPacked.bind(this);
        this.handleChangePacked = this.handleChangePacked.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/v1/clothes', {
            method: 'GET'
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(
                data => {
                    this.setState({
                        clothes: data
                    });
                },
                error => {
                    this.setState({
                        error
                    });
                });
    }

    deleteClothes(id) {
        fetch(`/api/v1/clothes/${id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE'
        })
            .then(() => {
                let updatedClothes = [...this.state.clothes].filter(i => i.id !== id);
                this.setState({
                    clothes: updatedClothes
                });
            });
    }

    isPacked(e) {
        if (e) {
            return <div>Yes</div>;
        }
    }

    handleChangePacked(e) {
        if (e) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    updateItem(id, item, packed) {
        fetch(`/api/v1/clothes/${id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ id, item, packed })
        })
            .then(() => {
                let updatedClothes = [...this.state.clothes].map(i => i.id === id ? { ...i, packed } : i);
                this.setState({
                    clothes: updatedClothes
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { clothes, error } = this.state;

        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        }

        const clothesList = clothes.map(c => {
            return <tr key={c.id}>
                <td>{c.id}</td>
                <td>{c.item}</td>
                <td>{this.isPacked(c.packed)}</td>
                <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => this.deleteClothes(c.id)}>Delete</button>
                    <button
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        onClick={() => this.updateItem(c.id, c.item, this.handleChangePacked(c.packed))}>
                        Update Item
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Clothes</h3>
                <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th>Packed</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {clothesList}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ClothesList;
```

I had to write two new functions:

```
isPacked(e) {
        if (e) {
            return <div>Yes</div>;
        }
}
```

and

```
handleChangePacked(e) {
        if (e) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
}
```

And then I modified update button:

```
<button
       className="btn btn-primary"
       onClick={() => this.updateItem(c.id, c.item, this.handleChangePacked(c.packed))}>
       Update Item
</button>
```

and `updateItem` function:

```
updateItem(id, item, packed) {
        fetch(`/api/v1/clothes/${id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ id, item, packed })
        })
            .then(() => {
                let updatedClothes = [...this.state.clothes].map(i => i.id === id ? { ...i, packed } : i);
                this.setState({
                    clothes: updatedClothes
                });
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t anything in the component that’s setting state for Id and packed

```
updateItem(id) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      packed: true,
      id,
    })

    const { item, packed } = this.state;

    fetch(`/api/v1/clothes/${id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ item, packed })
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. I still have "400 (Bad Request)".

Comment: @Marek means it’s a bad request from the client, we need to see what we should pass to the api for this to work

Comment: I have included "Swagger Request" to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

You can update it, like this

```
fetch(`/api/v1/clothes/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ item, packed })
}).then(data => {
    // ------------ START ------------
    let updatedClothes = this.state.clothes.map(i => i.id === id ? { ...i , packed} : i);
    this.setState({
        clothes: updatedClothes,
    });
    // ------------ END ------------
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. I want to click a button "Update Item" to updating state in a column "Packed" for "Yes" or "null" (for one element).

Comment: @Marek change this ` { ...i , packed}` to `{ ...i , packed : true}` , in abloce code and try

Comment: It works, but only on Front-end and only for "true" value. I need to send it to a database on Back-end.

Comment: `JSON.stringify({ item, packed: true })` send in the body like this. Also try with `isPacked :true` misplace of `packed`

Comment: I think you need to debug it from backend side ,like what parameters you are getting and what is should be